# Flex container that is wrapping expands to fill too much horizontal space

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want the flex container to adhere to the shape of its children, and not over expand horizontally, even when it is wrapping. Is this possible? Or should I be using some other approach, like media queries for narrow screens? Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/Marshjek/pen/KQZVBQ

Here is my current css, inline-flex does not cover the wrapping case:

```
.flex-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet into your question, not in an external site. This is so your question is useful for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example